# "Hidden text" inflates `widthof`

Tags: minipage, letters, datetime2, calc

French letters call for a heading stating place and date, which I put in `\letterlieudate`, which I put in a `minipage`. Requirement: that the `minipage`'s width be just big enough so that `\letterlieudate` fits on one line. Two options:  1) type the date manually, or 2) using `\today` (and a cmd to set the style just preceding it). Only 1) does the job right. With 2) the width is overestimated. Why and how can I remedy this problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[showdow, fr-FR]{datetime2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
a4paper
%,scale=0.8
%,showframe%for testing
]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\vspace*{-1cm}}
\usepackage{lipsum}%for testing
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%definitions--------------------------------------
\DTMsetdatestyle{ddmmyyyy}
\DTMsetup{datesep={/}}
\def\letterplace{Paris}
\def\letterdate{\today}
%\def\letterlieudate{À Paris, le 23/10/2019.} %option 1
\def\letterlieudate{À Paris, le \letterdate.} %option 2
\def\letterlieudatewidth{\widthof{\letterlieudate}} %TODO

%commands-----------------------------------------

\NewDocumentCommand{\myheading}
{O{}+mO{\newline}}
{\noindent #1#2#3}
\NewDocumentCommand{\shiftheading}{O{0.8}+mO{\letterlieudatewidth}}
{%
  \makebox[#1\textwidth][r]
  {%
  \frame{%for testing
    \begin{minipage}{#3}%
      \begin{flushleft}#2\end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}}
  }
}    


\begin{document}%---------------------------------
\thispagestyle{empty}

\shiftheading{%
  \myheading[%
  \DTMsetdatestyle{ddmmyyyy}%option 2
  ]
  {\letterlieudate}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Shot-1]
[image: Shot-2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `babel` package interferes with your default setting of `\DTMsetdatestyle` in the preamble by overriding the setting at `\begin{document}`. When your `\shiftheading` macro is executed then, `#3` gets the width of `\letterlieudate` with `\letterdate` having the global date setting, while the new setting is applied only inside the `minipage` environment. As a result the pre-computed width and the actual text's width differ.

A simple fix is to put

```
\DTMsetdatestyle{ddmmyyyy}
\DTMsetup{datesep={/}}
```

after `\begin{document}`.